# BUnit: How to test rendering a bound value in a razor based test

Tags: blazor, bunit

I'm trying to test rendering a property (Firstname) bound to a custom component.

My real structure looks like

```html
<div>
  <EditForm EditContext=editCtx>
    <MyCustomInputComponent @bind-Value="testModel.Firstname" ...></MyCustomInputComponent>
  </EditForm>
  <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO TEST -->
  <p id="result">@testModel.Firstname</p>
</div
```

In my test I simulated an input, changing the value of the component and test if the bound property was changed correctly. This works.

But the changed property-value is not rendered into the `<p>` element.

Here I have a **oversimplified example** of what I'm trying to do:

```cs
@using Bunit.Rendering;
@using NUnit.Framework;

@code {
  [Test]
  public void SimpleBindingTest()
  {
    using var ctx = new Bunit.TestContext();
    var person = new PersonTestModel();
    var cut = ctx.Render(@<p>@person.Firstname</p>);

    // Here my component would change the model
    // For simplicity I just change it
    person.Firstname = "John";

    // Render the content again because I don't have anything to call "StateHasChanged"
    var renderedComponent = (IRenderedComponent<IComponent>)cut;
    renderedComponent.Render();

    var pElement = cut.Find("p");
    // Fails, because the value is still empty -> <p></p>
    pElement.MarkupMatches("<p>John</p>");
  }
}
```

I try to trigger a re-render, after changing the bound value, similar to the description in the docs "[Triggering a render life cycle on a component](https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/trigger-renders.html)".

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all? Because, as you can see, I don't even test rendering a component. It is just HTML with a bound property.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your oversimplified version (`ctx.Render(@<p>@person.Firstname</p>);`) is that you are not "passing down" parameters. So, once you change `person.Firstname`, that `RenderFragment` has no concept of `Parameters` and therefore "doesn't see the change".

If we go away from the oversimplification and back to a real-world test: You would either invoke something inside your `MyCustomInputComponent` like a input-change, button click (`cut.FindComponent<MyCustomInputComponent>().Find("button").Click()`) to trigger a new render cycle, or, if you change the bound variable inside your test, yes you need to re-render the component under test.

So it is possible: Yes.
Without a minimal reproducible example, it is hard to help out here.

If you want, you can head over to our repository: https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/discussions

Answer (score 0):

@Link, thanks for your help.

I created an [entry in bunit gitub repository](https://github.com/bUnit-dev/bUnit/discussions/1282), where I got a good explanation why my approach doesn't work.

My root component is plain HTML, not a Blazor component, therefore it doesn't take part on Blazors live-cycle  functionality.

The fix is to create a wrapping component and put the content of my previous apporoach inside.

It is easier to explain it with code:

Here is the **TestWrapperComponent** which can be used as root component for my test.

```cs
<div>
  @this.ChildContent
</div>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; } = null!;

  public void Refresh()
  {
    this.StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

And the test looks like this:

```cs
@using Bunit.Rendering;
@using NUnit.Framework;
@using BlazorDemo.Model;
@using BlazorDemo.Components;
@inherits Bunit.TestContext;

@code {
  [Test]
  public void SimpleBindingTest()
  {
    using var ctx = new Bunit.TestContext();
    var person = new Person();
    var cut = ctx.Render(
      @<TestWrapperComponent>
        <p>@person.Firstname</p>
      </TestWrapperComponent>
    );

    // Here my component would change the model
    // For simplicity I just change it
    person.Firstname = "John";

    // Get the component and call a method that invokes "StateHasChanged".
    var renderedComponent = (IRenderedComponent<IComponent>)cut;
    var wrapperComponent = renderedComponent.FindComponent<TestWrapperComponent>();
    wrapperComponent.InvokeAsync(() => wrapperComponent.Instance.Refresh());

    var pElement = cut.Find("p");
    // Passes
    pElement.MarkupMatches("<p>John</p>");
  }
}
```